# How can I render a date value in date input field with Angular?

Tags: html, angular, date

I'm using Angular (4) and as you will see, I'm new to this game!

I've got data coming from a server backend ok, dates are being parsed into TS objects ok by my service.

However, when I include a date type input, I get a value of 'dd/mm/yyyy' rather that the date from the model (Browser is Chrome).

In my template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="anObject.dateProperty"
   type="date" name="dateProperty"  required="required">
```

I have tried using placeholder and value attributes on the input element.

Else where in the same template file this displays the date as I would expect, so I'm comfortable the value is set:

```
{{anObject.dateProperty | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

What is the Angular way of rendering the value of a date into an HTML input field?